# Jenkins JobDSL ERROR: Found multiple extensions which provide method branchDiscoveryTrait with arguments []:

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using jenkins `jobDSL` plugin to generate my pipeline jobs from a `groovy` script, where I'm trying to create a multibranchPipelineJob as you can in the following line

```
 17 multibranchPipelineJob("projects/${project_name}/${component_name}") {
 18   branchSources {
 19     branchSource {
 20       source {
 21         git {
 22           remote(component.repository)
 23           credentialsId(component.credentials)
 24           traits {
 25             branchDiscoveryTrait()
 26             cleanBeforeCheckoutTrait()
 27           }
 28         }
 29       }
 30       strategy {
 31         defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
 32           props {
 33           }
 34         }
 35       }
 36     }
 37   }
 38   triggers {
 39     periodic(5)
 40   }
 41   orphanedItemStrategy {
 42     discardOldItems {
 43       // numToKeep(20)
 44     }
 45   }
 46   if (component.jenkinsfile) {
 47     factory {
 48       workflowBranchProjectFactory {
 49         scriptPath(component.jenkinsfile)
 50       }
 51     }
 52   }
 53 }
```

When the main pipeline job executing this code runs, it raises this (apparently know) error :

> ERROR: Found multiple extensions which provide method
> branchDiscoveryTrait with arguments []:
> [[com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BranchDiscoveryTrait,
> jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait,
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.BranchDiscoveryTrait]]
> [image]

I've searched and see many results where people say that we should add `@Symbol` annotations to the `traits` implementations or to the relevant descriptors.

But I don't understand exactly what to do and where to place that `@Symbol`, people seem to say it solves the issue, but there is nowhere a good explanation and guidance to apply the fix.

should the modification be done in the plugin code or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the specific `git` scm class, and the correct syntax was :

```
 17 multibranchPipelineJob("projects/${project_name}/${component_name}") {
 18   branchSources {
 19     branchSource {
 20       source {
 21         git {
 22           remote(component.repository)
 23           credentialsId(component.credentials)
 24           traits {
 25             gitBranchDiscovery()
 26             cleanBeforeCheckoutTrait {
 27               extension {
 28                 deleteUntrackedNestedRepositories(false)
 29               }
 30             }
 31           }
 32         }
 33       }
 34       strategy {
 35         defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
 36           props {
 37           }
 38         }
 39       }
 40     }
 41   }
 42   triggers {
 43     periodic(5)
 44   }
 45   orphanedItemStrategy {
 46     discardOldItems {
 47       // numToKeep(20)
 48     }
 49   }
 50   if (component.jenkinsfile) {
 51     factory {
 52       workflowBranchProjectFactory {
 53         scriptPath(component.jenkinsfile)
 54       }
 55     }
 56   }
 57 }
```

Comment: For anyone struggling to grok the diff, the snippet above uses `gitBranchDiscovery()` instead of `branchDiscoveryTrait()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use bitbucketBranchDiscovery() instead of branchDiscoveryTrait()